# How can I supersede the built-in swipe gesture recognizer in UICollectionView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6, uicollectionview

We're building an app that takes advantage of the new UICollectionView in iOS 6.  However, we need to implement a long-press behavior such that even if the user then moves their finger after, we want it ignored.

i.e.

```
User touches the screen than instantly moves -> Swipe
User touches the screen, pauses, then moves -> Ignore swipe and wait for the release.
```

Basically, we only want to allow the built-in swipe gesture to be enabled if our gesture recognizer fails.  However, we're not sure how to supersede the built-in swipe gesture recognizers with that 'Other recognizer must fail first' logic.

We're not sure if we're allowed to simply walk the chain trying to find the UIScrollView and interrogate that as we don't know if that violates Apple's guidelines, and if I remember correctly, they actually warn against messing with their recognizers anyway.

So how can we create tap-to-hold recognizers that supersede the built in ones?

Comment: did you try implementing a longpressgesturerecognizer, when fired, would disable the collectionview swipability?

Comment: Not sure where to implement it.  And I believe you have to set the swipe gesture recognizer to only be active if the other one fails, which means I have to get an instance of that recognizer, which is what this question is about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an example on page 36 of the [UICollectionView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];

NSArray* recognizers = [self.collectionView gestureRecognizers];

// Make the default gesture recognizer wait until the custom one fails.
for (UIGestureRecognizer* aRecognizer in recognizers) {
    if ([aRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [aRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapGesture];
    }
}

// Now add the gesture recognizer to the collection view.
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

**Original answer**

Have a look at `UITapGestureRecognizerDelegate`, which can be used to allow two gesture recognizers to process touches at once:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {        
     return YES;
}
```

For more info, see a tutorial such as this:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

Comment: That's just it... I want the opposite.  I *dont* want the built-in swipe gesture recognizer (that the UIScrollView uses) to be recognized so long as the long press recognizer is valid (i.e. as stated above, if I tap-and-hold (long press) and move my finger while it is still down, I *don't* want the Swipe recognizer to treat that as a swipe.  I only want the swipe to work if the long-press doesn't happen.  I'll check out Ray's link.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, Ray's page linked to Apple's programming guide for UICollectionView http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf, which, on page 36 showed me how to do exactly what I wanted, so even though your example doesn't actually answer the question (I'd recommend updating it so it does) you're getting the vote.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Before your new `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` transnitions from the *possible* state, he will ask its delegate `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:`. You can use that delegate method to cancel (force to *failed* state) any other gesture recogniser attached to the same view.

You do this by implementing the following as a delegate for your new `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`:

```
@implementation DragPictogramGestureRecognizerDelegate

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in gestureRecognizer.view.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([gr isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] == NO) {
            gr.enabled = NO;
            gr.enabled = YES;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Further more, in order to allow the user to use your new `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with one finger, and use another finger to scroll the `UICollectionView` at the same time, you can implement the following delegate in the same class.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```