# Swipe gesture on imageview inside image view collection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to add a swipe gesture to an image located in an `UICollectionView`

This is my existing hierarchy:

[image]

I've tried adding the swipe gesture to the `UICollectionView` as well as the `UICollectionViewCell` representing the image but neither worked.

In another `UIViewController` I have a `UITableViewCell` to which I added the swipe gesture and everything works fine so I'm sure my gesture initialization is correct, I'm adding the gesture to the `UICollectionView` at the method `viewDidLoad`, is that the right place or should I place it in different method?

Comment: This thread should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411586/how-can-i-supersede-the-built-in-swipe-gesture-recognizer-in-uicollectionview

Comment: @antrix I went over the example you send as well as the attached guide, from what i read and understood the steps I'm doing are right, creating the swipe gesture --> adding it to the UICollectionView should worked, as I'm not overriding the tap or long tap I see no reason to work with the inherited gestureRecognizers, a working example could be great